# Android create handler inside thread into Service

Tags: android, android-service

i'm writing simple android service and i want to use such as `Toast` or `Notification` but i get this error:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-17116
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

i can not use `runOnUiThread` . my service does not know that. for example i try to use that with : `this`, `getBaseContect()`, `getApplication`, `mContext` for `.runOnUiThread(new  Runnable() {}`

i get problem and i can not resolve problem.

this is my code:

```
public class TsmsService extends Service {

    private Timer smsThread;
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    private SQLiteDatabase dbHelper;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        smsThread = new Timer();
        GetSMSThread getSMSThread = new GetSMSThread(getBaseContext());
        smsThread.scheduleAtFixedRate(getSMSThread, 0, 1000); //(timertask,delay,period)
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public class GetSMSThread extends TimerTask {
        private Context mContext;

        public GetSMSThread(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            this.runOnUiThread(new  Runnable() {
                public  void  run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication() , "Service is Running ... " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Service  is use for background task...for update application use broadcast or handler ..you cant update directly from Service .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try creating a Handler in onStartCommand (so, from the UI thread). Then use that Handler to trigger the Toast. For example:

```
private Handler mToastHandler = null;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    ...
    mToastHandler = new Handler();
    ...
}

...

    // from inside your child thread
    mToastHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(...);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use [ResultReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html) that is used for the purpose of receiving a callback result from someone. In your case its [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

You can check the [complete example of Service with TimerTask using ResultReceiver](https://github.com/lalit3686/ResultReceiverDemo/tree/master/src/com/result/receiver) for updating the UI inside Activity